# Tailwind peer out of radio div

Tags: html, css, radio-button, tailwind-css

Unable to find in official documentation it is possible to use peer out of div where located radio buttons?
I try this but this not work .

Code Example :

```
<div>
    <label for="head-company" class="block text-xs font-medium mb-0.5">Payment
        terms</label>
    <!-- tabs -->
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 rounded-xl bg-basic-white p-0.5" x-data="app">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="cred"
                class="peer hidden flex items-center py-2.5 px-4 relative rounded-lg active:bg-turquoise-600 active:text-basic-white hover:bg-turquoise-600 hover:text-basic-white focus:bg-turquoise-600 focus:text-basic-white"
                checked />
            <label for="cred"
                class="block cursor-pointer select-none rounded-xl p-2 text-center peer-checked:bg-turquoise-600  peer-checked:text-basic-white">
                CIA
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="option" id="2" class="peer/cred hidden" />
            <label for="2"
                class="block cursor-pointer select-none rounded-xl p-2 text-center peer-checked/cred:bg-turquoise-600 peer-checked/cred:text-basic-white">
                Credit terms
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="new-trade__input-group peer-checked/cred:bg-turquoise-600  peer-checked/cred:hidden">
    <div class="input-text-group">
        <label for="head-company" class="input-text-group__label">Credit
            Terms</label>
        <div class="input-text-group__wrap">
            <input class="max-w-[96px]" type="text" id="fname" name="fname"
                placeholder="Max">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `peer out`

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I mean "peer" out of div which contains a checkbox